# How to copy column/row reference of a file to link in Markdown?

Tags: python, github, pycharm, markdown

I want to forward to the specific column in the python file when selecting the link from markdown. I copied the reference fom PyCharm but it wont work in markdown file. Is there any way to do this?

```
[Link](Python_folder/py_file.py:15)
```

Comment: Would you like to navigate inside PyCharm or Github?

Comment: Navigate in GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github supports relative links. However, it has a bit different syntax than PyCharm.

```markdown
[Link](Python_folder/py_file.py#L15)
```

Copy reference for Github isn't implemented yet ([IDEA-91608](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91608)), but you can use *Open In | Github* action (configure a remote repository first via *Git | Manage Remotes*) and copy relative path.

[image]

[image]